# How to make a manifest file

Tags: javascript, html, manifest

I have made a web app, and I am new to javascript. How can i make a manifest file with an html, css, and javascript file? I want to know so I can make a mobile web app.

Comment: are you on about the cache manifest? if so http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML5, JavaScript and CSS3 don't define any manifest. The manifest is usually a XML file. If you use PhoneGap, for example, you have to make a manifest, but there is not part of the HTML5 technology